# Giving unique id to table cell

Tags: javascript, cell

I have created a table.

I have text input where I type some text. It refers to some element with special values.

When I click a button the `productname` is added to the table (using `insertCell()`).

I want to give a unique id to every new table element.

```
function add1() {
  var row, cell;
  var productname = document.getElementById("produkt1").value; // text input
  var table = document.getElementById("pos1"); // button near text input

  if(productname === "Egg") {
    p = ["Egg", "", 20, 10, 11, 101];
  }
  if(productname === "Milk") {
    p = ["Milk", "", 30, 5, 12, 75];
  }

  row = table.insertRow(2);
  var c_id = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < p.length ; i++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = p[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < 1 ; j++) {
      cell.id = 'tdp1' + k_id;
      c_id++; 
    }
  } // It only works for one element, and the others have the same id as elements from row1
}
```

Comment: where are the variables `p` and `k_id` declared? where do you increment `k_id`? and you're not using `c_id`. and this loop `for(var j = 0; j < 1 ; j++){` makes no sense, since you always iterate exactly once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
function add1() {
var row, cell;
var productname = document.getElementById("produkt1").value;
var table = document.getElementById("pos1");
if(productname === "Egg") {
p = ["Egg", "", 20, 10, 11, 101];
}
if(productname === "Milk") {
p = ["Milk", "", 30, 5, 12, 75];
}
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("pos");
row = table.insertRow(2);
for(var i = 0; i < p.length ; i++){
cell = row.insertCell(i);
cell.innerHTML = p[i];
cell.className = "pos";
for(var j = 0; j < cells.length ; j++){
cell.id = 'tdp1' + j;
}
}
```

I gave created cell a className. It's working, but thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

a. There seems to be a type in the line `cell.id = 'tdp1' + k_id;` It is supposed to be `c_id` instead of `k_id`

b. You do not need the second for loop for anything and just can remove it.
The following code gives me a new row with ids for each cell (tdp10 to tdp15)

```
function add1() {
  var row, cell;
  var productname = document.getElementById("produkt1").value; // text input
  var table = document.getElementById("pos1"); // button near text input
  if(productname === "Egg") {
      p = ["Egg", "", 20, 10, 11, 101];
  }
  if(productname === "Milk") {
      p = ["Milk", "", 30, 5, 12, 75];
  }
  row = table.insertRow(2);
  var c_id = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < p.length ; i++){
      cell = row.insertCell(i);
      cell.innerHTML = p[i];
      cell.id = 'tdp1' + c_id;
      c_id++; 
  }
}
```